# Passing values from a button to View Controller dictionary

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to pass specific data from a button in a collection view cell (title of the button) to the view controller and put that value in an array. I have a CollectionViewCell.swift and ViewController.swift and would like to pass the string from CollectionViewCell.swift and append it to an array in the ViewController.swift. Not sure how to pass it into the ViewController.swift and how to add that value to an array into the View Controller file.

Struct Operation didn't work for me.  Not sure how to pass data specific to the button to the ViewController.swift when the button is pressed.

```
@IBAction func myButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let name = sender.title(for: .normal) ?? String()
        //I Want to send name to view controller and put it into an array in the ViewController.swift
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protocol collectionViewCellDelegate {
    func sendBackTheName(string : String)
}
```

in collectionViewCell.swift

```
var delegate : collectionViewCellDelegate? 

@IBAction func myButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let name = sender.title(for: .normal) ?? String()
        //I Want to send name to view controller and put it into an array in the ViewController.swift
        delegate?.sendBackTheName(string : name)
}
```

in viewController.swift , add this line,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // do your works
    cell.delegate = self 
    return cell
}

extension ViewController : collectionViewCellDelegate {
    func sendBackTheName(string : String) {
       array.append(string) // assuming array is declared previously
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I add the collection View in the View Controller class or outside of the class?  Same with the extension ViewController line?

Comment: Yeah, as your viewController contains the collection view. Extensions are written outside the class, anywhere in the module.